# What potion can I easily create?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to sell potions, but need to know which potion is the fastest and easiest to create?

What ingredients are needed to create these potions and where can I find them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One of the easiest and most useful potions to make is Restore Health.  You can make these by the truckload with ingredients around Whiterun.  Look for:

- [Wheat](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Wheat) - which you can find as large bushels in the farms surrounding Whiterun, as well as some other farm locations in the plains west of Whiterun.  These bushels respawn, eventually, although it takes a couple of weeks.
- [Blue Mountain Flower](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blue_Mountain_Flower) - which is in abundant supply in the non-farm fields around Whiterun, and fairly common across the plains of Skyrim.
- [Butterfly Wing](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Butterfly_Wing) - these can also be found by catching the reddish/orange butterflies that flit about in the fields around Whiterun.

Mix these three things together, and you'll have a Restore Health potion.  Don't forget to check the alchemy shops in Whiterun and other major towns, as there's plenty of these low-level ingredients on offer, and once you have some alchemy ranks you can easily profit by crafting them into potions.  When shopping, look for [Blisterwort](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blisterwort) as well, although be careful of side effects from various ingredient mixes - which ones are dangerous is left as an exercise to the reader. :)

Now, for profit purposes, you'll want to throw a [Giant's Toe](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Giant%27s_Toe) into the mix.  Giant's Toes boost the potion's profitability by a crazy amount.  There's a list of locations in that linked article, or you can just kill giants, if you've got the levels for it.

Put those previous three ingredients together with the Toe, and you'll end up with a worthless potion/poison that has tremendous resale value.

Comment: The other thing you can use is any number of the Skyrim Online/Offline Potion Calculators. I use Skyrim Alchemist on my iPad but http://rp.eliteskills.com/skyrim.html is an ok online one. You put in all the ingredients you have on you and it will figure out which potions you can create and how profitable they will be when resold. Sort by profit and you will be on your way. It also helps to grab ANY ingredient you may come across during your travels.

Answer (score 3):

Not counting special ingredients like Giant's Toe which are difficult to get in quantity, you can mix `Blue Butterfly Wing` and `Blue Mountain Flower`.

There are a couple butterfly spawns by Honningbrew Meadery and the nearby crossroads/bridges. These particular spawns seem to reset when you enter and exit the meadery.

For the flowers, head north past the farms and Whitewatch Tower until you hit the road heading east and west between Dawnstar and Windhelm. As you approach this area you should find some.

For more ingredients, keep heading east and north(possibly go by Fort Fellhammer instead of the other fort for less bandits to deal with) and when you hit the fork in the road approaching Dawnstar, head west again. Go by dwemer ruins and Frostmere Crypt until you get to the Stone Hills mining community(massive butterfly spawn here, too). You should have encountered tons of blue mountain flower along the way.

This combo makes poisons of damage magicka regen, the 2nd most valuable alchemy effect after paralysis.

Comment: This is actually a decent answer, minus the fact it is currently a wall of text. I tried to make it more read-friendly. Points for details.

Comment: Gotta say, this answer I wrote looks a lot better after your edits. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

One easy potion i LOVE to use is...

- Giants toe + Blue mountain flower + Creep cluster
- Giants toe + Blue butterfly wing + Blue mountain flower
- Wheat + Blue mountain flower + Butterfly wing
- Giants toe + Wheat

So yeah, i hope i helped!

Comment: Hi Bug Z, welcome to Arqade! What makes this potion easily creatable as per the question? Are the materials easier to obtain? Also, What exactly does this potion do?

Comment: Also the way you type looks like a potion with 8 ingredients, will help if you format your text a little.

Answer (score -4):

nirnroot+deathbell+nightshade=damage health, I'm pretty sure

Comment: Do you think you can back yourself up? And probably clean up your post?