# What are the most valuable potion effects?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a new character, and I'm currently levelling both my Alchemy and Speechcraft, by crafting potions in a store and selling them to the merchant in order to buy more ingredients. However, most of my potions are worth fairly little.

I've noticed that a potion with "Slow" as an effect is worth anywhere from 400 - 600 gold, depending on secondary effects, compared to about 80 for a restore health potion. Are there more valuable effects I should be looking for?

Comment: Related: [What potion can I easily create?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/98261/4797), [What are the most profitable ingredients to plant?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/142118/4797)

Comment: So,,, a Giant's Toe really kicks the value up a bit. Made a potion worth 1500... why is that?

Comment: Giant's Toe is one of several non standard ingredients. Such ingredients can improve or hurt gold value of an effect, or improve or hurt the strength of an effect(which also has an impact on gold value). Giant's Toe happens to to multiply the gold value of Fortify health effect by almost 6x. Boar's Tusk from the Dragonborn DLC does the same for both Fortify Health and Fortify Stamina. Salmon Roe in the Hearthfire DLC makes the waterbreathing effect over 15 times as strong. That mixed with Garlic and Nordic Barnacle creates the most valuable mixture possible in the game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A user has asked a [similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35800/how-do-i-make-money-efficiently), concerning how to make money efficiently, and the accepted answer is to make potions of invisibility.

According to the [Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Invisibility_Potion#Alchemy), invisibility ingredients include

- Ash Creep Cluster
- Chaurus Eggs
- Crimson Nirnroot
- Ice Wraith Teeth
- Luna Moth Wing
- Nirnroot
- Vampire Dust

That said, purchasing ingredients from the merchants can be a very inefficient way to generate money. Vendors will charge more for the ingredients then the average yield for the potions - especially with higher quality potions that require more expensive reagents.

You might find it more beneficial to create low value potions. Consider how much the ingredients are being purchased for. Higher-value potions may not earn you back as much in comparison to lower-quality potions that require cheaper ingredients. You can generally make more of them at a time, due to availability of ingredients, in turn generating more experience. **The best value advice is to harvest your own ingredients,** but you appear to be favoring merchant ingredients for working on your speechcraft.

Comment: Use the calculators in the other answers, you will always make a profit.

Comment: @James, the calculators only ask what ingredients you already have. You can not assume that profit will be made if you assume how the ingredients were obtained, and OP already states purchasing ingredients from the merchant for the purpose of their question. Merchants are going to offer a lot of no-profit options, especially if speechcraft is low. Maybe if the calculator determined the cost of the ingredients, with eventual profit, it would be plausible.

Comment: I have always found a profit when buying their inventory, crafting it into the best priced potions possible and selling them back. I gain skill in Alchemy and Speech as well as coin for my pocket.. and usually have some potions left over to sell to some general merchant somewhere.

Comment: In general, I have found the complete opposite, especially in regards to high-value effects and their required reagents, and especially at earlier levels.

Answer (score 8):

In direct answer to your question, the most valuable potion effects (and their values when mixed without perks and a skill total of 100) are:

1. Paralysis (285)
2. Damage Magicka Regen (265)
3. Invisibility (261)
4. Slow (247)
5. Fortify Carry Weight(208)

I've noticed that Damage Magicka Regen and Slow *can* be combined by using some relatively exotic reagents for a total value of 512.

---

For an answer to the underlying question how to best profit from making potions or generate Alchemy experience, consider a potion made from:

- Creep Cluster
- Mora Tapinella
- Scaly Pholiota

You'll notice that these ingredients are remarkably common as compared to other suggestions and they produce a potion with the following 5(!) effects (and values as reported [here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alchemy_Effects)):

- Fortify Carry Weight (208)
- Fortify Illusion (94)
- Regenerate Samina (177)
- Restore Magicka (25)
- Weakness to Magic (51)

For a total value of 555 when made with no perks and a skill total of 100.  That's better than twice the value of Slow (247).  Throw in some perks & late game skill totals ( 100 base + 4 Fortify Alchemy enchantments @ up to 25 each if you're not doing your own enchants ) and the value gets very high.  Note that the Purity perk will neutralize the Weakness to Magic effect for a far more drinkable potion, but a 10% drop in sales value.

Best of all, if you've got [skyrim-hearthfire](/questions/tagged/skyrim-hearthfire), these 3 ingredients may be grown in the garden of your rural estate(s).  Plant 3 of the Creep Clusters and 5 of each of the mushrooms and you'll be able to harvest enough for 15 potions every few game days.  If you've got all 3 estates, that adds up to a pretty profit that will easily absorb the cash flows of every fence in the game.  Add in a Green House as the west wing of one or more of your estates and you're being gratuitous for profit purposes; or perhaps you are just grinding out Legendary Alchemy levels at little cost or effort?

Of course, between harvest days, feel free to make whatever potions you like from more exotic/expensive ingredients.

Comment: I love your planting advice. Small correction however. Optimal planting for 11 plants in garden is 3 Creep Clusters (harvest of 5 per plant), 5 Mora Tapinellas (harvest of 3 per plant) and 3 Scaly Pholiotas (harvest of 5 per plant).

Comment: Is there a complete list of effect values?

Comment: @TomášZato, Yup!  I've even included a link to said list in my answer.

Comment: @tjd Thanks. Turns out there are even better potions, see my answer.

Comment: @TomášZato, While I concur that their are more *valuable* potions, The point of my answer is maximizing value with easy to acquire reagents.  Of the ones you found only the Charus Eggs/Garlic/Luna Moth Wing recipe uses remarkably *common* ingredients it's just that you need to walk a little farther from your front door to collect them.  Still, good finds.

Answer (score 5):

I extracted data from [this page](http://www.uesp.net/w/index.php?title=Skyrim:Alchemy_Effects&article_action=edit#Effect_List) into [JSON](https://darker.github.io/skyrim/skyrim-potion-effects.js). Afterwards, I wrote three nested loops to generate all possible potions from all the ingredients that exist.

#### Without DLCs

Provided my algorithm is correct, there is a total of 17 461 potions that you can brew using any valid combination of two or three ingredients. From those, the following ones are the definite winners in the value category:

```
Effects                  │ Ingredients            │ Value │ Extensions
═════════════════════════╪════════════════════════╪═══════╪═══════════
Damage Magicka           │ Glow Dust              │       │           
Damage Magicka Regen     │ Glowing Mushroom       │       │           
Fortify Destruction      │ Hanging Moss           │ 636   │           
Fortify Health           │                        │       │           
Resist Shock             │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Damage Stamina Regen     │ Giant's Toe            │       │           
Fortify Carry Weight     │ Large Antlers          │ 614   │           
Slow                     │ River Betty            │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Damage Stamina Regen     │ Creep Cluster          │       │           
Fortify Carry Weight     │ Large Antlers          │ 614   │           
Slow                     │ River Betty            │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Damage Magicka Regen     │ Bear Claws             │       │           
Fortify Destruction      │ Glow Dust              │ 584   │           
Fortify Health           │ Glowing Mushroom       │       │           
Resist Shock             │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Damage Magicka Regen     │ Blue Mountain Flower   │       │           
Fortify Destruction      │ Glow Dust              │ 584   │           
Fortify Health           │ Glowing Mushroom       │       │           
Resist Shock             │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Damage Magicka Regen     │ Glow Dust              │       │           
Fortify Destruction      │ Glowing Mushroom       │ 584   │           
Fortify Smithing         │ Spriggan Sap           │       │           
Resist Shock             │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Damage Magicka           │ Chaurus Eggs           │       │           
Fortify Stamina          │ Garlic                 │ 561   │           
Invisibility             │ Luna Moth Wing         │       │           
Regenerate Health        │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Fortify Carry Weight     │ Creep Cluster          │       │           
Fortify Illusion         │ Mora Tapinella         │       │           
Regenerate Stamina       │ Scaly Pholiota         │ 555   │           
Restore Magicka          │                        │       │           
Weakness to Magic        │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Damage Magicka           │ Glow Dust              │       │           
Damage Magicka Regen     │ Glowing Mushroom       │ 554   │           
Fortify Destruction      │ Jarrin Root            │       │           
Resist Shock             │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Damage Magicka           │ Glow Dust              │       │           
Damage Magicka Regen     │ Glowing Mushroom       │ 554   │           
Fortify Destruction      │ Human Heart            │       │           
Resist Shock             │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Damage Magicka Regen     │ Canis Root             │       │           
Damage Stamina           │ Hanging Moss           │ 544   │           
Fortify Marksman         │ Spider Egg             │       │           
Fortify One-handed       │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Damage Magicka Regen     │ Bear Claws             │       │           
Damage Stamina           │ Canis Root             │ 544   │           
Fortify Marksman         │ Spider Egg             │       │           
Fortify One-handed       │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Damage Magicka           │ Bear Claws             │       │           
Damage Magicka Regen     │ Eye of Sabre Cat       │       │           
Fortify Health           │ Hanging Moss           │ 542   │           
Fortify One-handed       │                        │       │           
Restore Stamina          │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Fortify One-handed       │ Canis Root             │       │           
Fortify Sneak            │ Hawk Feathers          │ 521   │           
Paralysis                │ Human Flesh            │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Damage Magicka           │ Bear Claws             │       │           
Damage Magicka Regen     │ Hanging Moss           │ 517   │           
Fortify Health           │ Jarrin Root            │       │           
Fortify One-handed       │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Damage Magicka           │ Bear Claws             │       │           
Damage Magicka Regen     │ Hanging Moss           │ 517   │           
Fortify Health           │ Human Heart            │       │           
Fortify One-handed       │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Damage Magicka           │ Bear Claws             │       │           
Damage Magicka Regen     │ Butterfly Wing         │ 517   │           
Fortify Health           │ Hanging Moss           │       │           
Fortify One-handed       │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Damage Magicka           │ Bear Claws             │       │           
Damage Magicka Regen     │ Chaurus Eggs           │ 517   │           
Fortify Health           │ Hanging Moss           │       │           
Fortify One-handed       │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Damage Magicka           │ Bear Claws             │       │           
Damage Magicka Regen     │ Daedra Heart           │ 517   │           
Fortify Health           │ Hanging Moss           │       │           
Fortify One-handed       │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Damage Magicka           │ Bear Claws             │       │           
Damage Magicka Regen     │ Glow Dust              │ 517   │           
Fortify Health           │ Hanging Moss           │       │           
Fortify One-handed       │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Damage Magicka           │ Bear Claws             │       │           
Damage Magicka Regen     │ Hagraven Feathers      │ 517   │           
Fortify Health           │ Hanging Moss           │       │           
Fortify One-handed       │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Damage Magicka           │ Bear Claws             │       │           
Damage Magicka Regen     │ Hanging Moss           │ 517   │           
Fortify Health           │ Luna Moth Wing         │       │           
Fortify One-handed       │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Damage Magicka           │ Bear Claws             │       │           
Damage Magicka Regen     │ Hanging Moss           │ 517   │           
Fortify Health           │ Namira's Rot           │       │           
Fortify One-handed       │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Damage Magicka           │ Bear Claws             │       │           
Damage Magicka Regen     │ Hanging Moss           │ 517   │           
Fortify Health           │ Nordic Barnacle        │       │           
Fortify One-handed       │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Cure Disease             │ Hawk Feathers          │       │           
Fortify Light Armor      │ Luna Moth Wing         │ 514   │           
Invisibility             │ Vampire Dust           │       │           
Regenerate Health        │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Fortify Block            │ Briar Heart            │       │           
Paralysis                │ Pearl                  │ 514   │           
Resist Shock             │ Swamp Fungal Pod       │       │           
Restore Magicka          │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Fortify Stamina          │ Chaurus Eggs           │       │           
Invisibility             │ Garlic                 │ 509   │           
Regenerate Health        │ Vampire Dust           │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Damage Magicka           │ Daedra Heart           │       │           
Damage Stamina Regen     │ Juniper Berries        │ 508   │           
Fear                     │ Namira's Rot           │       │           
Regenerate Health        │                        │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
Fortify Carry Weight     │ Creep Cluster          │       │           
Slow                     │ River Betty            │ 506   │           
Weakness to Magic        │ Salt Pile              │       │           
─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────
```

#### With all DLCs

Skyrim extensions add another 11 354 potion possibilities, adding up to total of 28 815 unique potion recipes. These are honorable mentions:

```
Effects                  │ Ingredients             │ Value │ Extensions    
═════════════════════════╪═════════════════════════╪═══════╪═══════════════
Fear                     │ Gleamblossom            │       │               
Fortify Carry Weight     │ Netch Jelly             │       │               
Paralysis                │ Wisp Wrappings          │ 689   │ [DG] [DB]     
Resist Magic             │                         │       │               
Restore Stamina          │                         │       │               
─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────────
Fear                     │ Gleamblossom            │       │               
Fortify Carry Weight     │ Hawk Beak               │ 638   │ [DG] [DB]     
Paralysis                │ Netch Jelly             │       │               
Restore Stamina          │                         │       │               
─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────────
Damage Magicka           │ Daedra Heart            │       │               
Fear                     │ Poison Bloom            │ 627   │ [DG] [DB]     
Fortify Carry Weight     │ Trama Root              │       │               
Slow                     │                         │       │               
─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────────
Damage Magicka           │ Namira's Rot            │       │               
Fear                     │ Poison Bloom            │ 627   │ [DG] [DB]     
Fortify Carry Weight     │ Trama Root              │       │               
Slow                     │                         │       │               
─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────────
Damage Health            │ Human Flesh             │       │               
Fear                     │ Netch Jelly             │ 616   │ [DG] [DB]     
Fortify Carry Weight     │ Poison Bloom            │       │               
Paralysis                │                         │       │               
─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────────
Damage Health            │ Imp Stool               │       │               
Fear                     │ Netch Jelly             │ 616   │ [DG] [DB]     
Fortify Carry Weight     │ Poison Bloom            │       │               
Paralysis                │                         │       │               
─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────────
Damage Stamina Regen     │ Giant's Toe             │       │               
Fortify Carry Weight     │ Large Antlers           │ 614   │ [DG]          
Slow                     │ Poison Bloom            │       │               
─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────────
Damage Stamina Regen     │ Creep Cluster           │       │               
Fortify Carry Weight     │ Large Antlers           │ 614   │ [DG]          
Slow                     │ Poison Bloom            │       │               
─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────────
Damage Stamina Regen     │ Giant's Toe             │       │               
Fortify Carry Weight     │ Large Antlers           │ 614   │ [DB]          
Slow                     │ Trama Root              │       │               
─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────────
Damage Stamina Regen     │ Creep Cluster           │       │               
Fortify Carry Weight     │ Large Antlers           │ 614   │ [DB]          
Slow                     │ Trama Root              │       │               
─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────────
Fear                     │ Gleamblossom            │       │               
Fortify Carry Weight     │ Netch Jelly             │ 613   │ [DG] [DB]     
Paralysis                │ Poison Bloom            │       │               
─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────────
Fear                     │ Briar Heart             │       │               
Fortify Carry Weight     │ Netch Jelly             │ 613   │ [DG] [DB]     
Paralysis                │ Poison Bloom            │       │               
─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────────
Fear                     │ Netch Jelly             │       │               
Fortify Carry Weight     │ Poison Bloom            │ 613   │ [DG] [DB]     
Paralysis                │ Swamp Fungal Pod        │       │               
─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────────
Fear                     │ Gleamblossom            │       │               
Fortify Carry Weight     │ Netch Jelly             │ 613   │ [DG] [DB]     
Paralysis                │ Scaly Pholiota          │       │               
─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────────
Fortify Carry Weight     │ Hawk Beak               │       │               
Paralysis                │ Netch Jelly             │ 604   │ [DB]          
Resist Shock             │ Swamp Fungal Pod        │       │               
Restore Stamina          │                         │       │               
─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────────
Fear                     │ Large Antlers           │       │               
Fortify Carry Weight     │ Netch Jelly             │ 600   │ [DG] [DB]     
Restore Stamina          │ Poison Bloom            │       │               
Slow                     │                         │       │               
─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────┼───────────────
```

DG stands for DawnGuard, DB for Dragonborn.

#### Source

The script can be seen here: https://darker.github.io/skyrim/potion_value.html

However, it has no UI. For options, search for following comments in code:

- `Potion filtering` - allows you to exclude potions from output based on their type
- `Potion sorting` - self explanatory
- `Output type` - switch between HTML and ASCII output

Comment: +1.  All good finds.  I still prefer the 555 value potion you can collect from your hearthfire gardens, but that 561 value potion looks like a great way to burn some remarkably common ingredients.  Definitely worth special mention!

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some basic guidelines but you will ultimately want to find a tool like this one: http://rp.eliteskills.com/skyrim.html You can put in your ingredients and it will give you the most expensive potion combinations you can make. This is also very good for just figuring out ingredients if you don't want to guess and not really waste materials.

The guidelines are this though, you want as many effects as you can possibly put into a single potion. It does not matter helpful or hurtful purity. An additional effect on the potion will result to additional value.

The next thing you want to take a look at are going to be the effects. Common health potions, as you saw, are not as worth while as things like Slow, Paralysis. Other effects that tend to be a high price point are Regeneration Buffs or Debuffs as well. Ones that raise skills are also a bit useful.

Why I can't say just pick one of these types is that you want to find which combinations you can make with your ingredients to get the most bang for your buck. That is where the calculator I linked before makes it easier. You can also find a mod that will do this same thing for you in-game (but its a little ... bit buggy last time I tried it).

NOTE: There are going to be some exceptions to this due to ingredient rarity. For example if you take the root given to you in the course of the Dark Brotherhood quest, it will give you a [Very expensive poison](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47339/how-high-can-poison-damage-go).

Answer (score 0):

You want value? Combine the following slow poison

Salt pile

Deathbell

River betty

It makes a damage health (poison) and slows, meaning at a higher alchemy level, it will be your friend both in value and combat

Answer (score 0):

For low levels, I recommend the Blue Potion. This is not, of course, the name of it the game. It's a potion that requires on blue mountain flower and one blue butterfly wing, ingredients that are ridiculously common everywhere in Skyrim. The effects are fortify conjuration and damage magicka regeneration. It's completely useless for personal use, but it's worth a ton.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Skyrim Alchemy Calculator](https://arrington.me/alch/) to input all ingredients you have.

It will tell you what you can craft and how much each potion is worth.